# Ant build.xml link error LNK 1104:cannot open file

Tags: ant, jenkins, visual-studio-2005

My projects are compiling successfully from Visual studio 2005, but not from my apache ant script manually using my project’s build.xml file.  I get this error:

```
Error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\tcp\workspace\speed\clear\zlib\../../lib/zlib.libc:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\tcp\workspace\speed\clear\utils\../../lib/utils.lib'
```

This particular project `coms` depends on two libraries `zlib` and `utils`

Linker has concatenated two lib files. So it’s not able to find it, while all these dependency libraries are defined independently.

I am giving the relative path to the `lib` folder in `Additional Library Directories`

The same project `coms` compiles successfully from Visual Studio 2005

Comment: There's nothing separating the paths: "zlib.libc:\Program Files (x86)". There's probably a missing semi-colon somewhere.

Comment: Hi Chad,

Libraries are listed separately with spaces and quotes in properties file(.vcproj).
All these files are checked out from trunk and its working there.

The project is not working on Windows Server 2008
BUT...
Same project works on windows 7 system (Seems to me that it is not a missing semicolon related error)

Could it be a environment related issue...??

Comment: After upgrading to MS Visual Studio 2005 SP1, the linking errors are gone. There are known linking errors in original 2005 setup, so the solution for such kind of problems is upgrade to SP1.